# Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm using `biblatex`, and am still very new at it.

I can't figure out how to suppress certain fields automatically generated from my `bibtex` file into my `.bbl` file. For instance, for all of my entries, I have a category `Language` in which I record the language that that work was written in. This is just for my own database, and I don't want this information listed in the References at the end of my `article`/`book`. But it gets listed anyway. The same is true of my `notes` field. Is there anyway to suppress a specific field so that it does not show up in the "List of References"?

I would write my own style, but my knowledge of programming/TeX is not even close to being able to do that. I've noticed there is a solution for the ISBN number (an option `isbn=false`), and this is exactly what I need, but for different fields.

Answer (score 53):

The command `\clearlist` can be used to suppress a category. You can read more details in the documenation

```
texdoc biblatex
```

In the MWE below I have used `filecontents*` to create the bibliography, but if you already have a `.bib` file then you can delete these lines.

```
% this part creates mybib.bib
% delete these lines if you already have a .bib file
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{Ab_Steg,
 author = "M. Abramowitz and I. A. Stegun",
 title = {Handbook of mathematical functions},
 publisher = "Dover publications",
 year = "1965",
 language="English" }
\end{filecontents*}
% end delete

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\bibliography{mybib}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} % clears language
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}    % clears notes

\begin{document}

hello world \cite{Ab_Steg}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The compilation sequence is

```
pdflatex myfile.tex
biber myfile.bcf
pdflatex myfile.tex
pdflatex myfile.tex
```

(You don't have to use the extensions if you don't want to.)

Comment: Thank you very much, cmhughes, for the advice!
It worked perfectly to suppress the information from the "Language" field, which is a variable of the \list command in the generated .bib file.
And it led me to the solution for the other field I wanted to suppress: "note" - however, the "note" field is a variable of the \field command, so \clearlist{} doesn't work, but \clearfield{} does, as in: \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}}

Comment: @cmhughes Would you mind commenting on why you used '\clearlist' in the first case and '\clearfield' in the second?

Comment: @louiscypher see Jeutzsch comment above

Comment: @cmhughes Sorry I must have had tomatoes on my eyes

Comment: Just in case someone tried to clear list of names like *editors*: `\clearlist` didn't work for me, but `\clearname` did.

Comment: I needed `\clearfield`

Answer (score 35):

If you are using Biber rather than BibTeX, you can supress/map any fields before BibLaTeX even sees them. See section 3.1.1 of the Biber PDF manual. For example, in your case, you could put this in your biber.conf (version 0.9.8+):

```xml
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_set="LANGUAGE" map_null="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="NOTES" map_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

You can also do this only for specific entrytypes. See the Biber manual. There is a also a document level macro interface to this, see the biblatex 2.0+ manual. In your preamble, you could do the following, which is equivalent to the above:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=language, null]
      \step[fieldset=notes, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for my in clearing the issn field. The other answer did not work for issn for some reason.

Comment: Curious why `datatype=bibtex` is `bibtex` not `biblatex`
. But it works.

Comment: The data itself is `bibtex` format data which `biblatex` can read (here, via the program `biber`)