# biblatex URL shown twice in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, urls

I didn't find a solution in the web, so I'm asking here.

I am using `authoryear-icomp` style for my bibliography (without any modification). When I have a BibTeX entry like:

```
@online{guizzo_i-limb_2008,
title = {{i-LIMB} snatches {MacRobert} Award - {IEEE} Spectrum},
url = {http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/ilimb_snatches_macrobert_award},
abstract = {{IEEE} Spectrum},
journal = {{IEEE} Spectrum},
author = {Guizzo, Erico},
month = jun,
year = {2008}
},
```

I get the URL twice in the bibliography. Once in the `url` field with nice linebreaks and once rudely running into the margins:

```
Guizzo, Erico (June 2008). i-LIMB snatches MacRobert Award - IEEE Spectrum.
http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/ilimb_snatches_macrobert_award.
URL: http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/ilimb_
snatches_macrobert_award.
```

How do I get rid of the entry not starting with `URL` (that is the one without linebreak)?

Comment: Btw, I'd recommend replacing the hyphen `-` in your title (`MacRobert Award - IEEE Spectrum`) by an en dash `--` or em dash `---`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a matter of some old files in the temp directory par-username. There has been a  `howpublished = {http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/ilimb\_snatches\_macrobert\_award}` entry that is not wrapped.

Comment: BTW: disabling howpublished by \printbibliography[nottype=howpublished] does not work sadly. I have to delete the howpublished entry

Comment: `type` and `nottype` specify an entry type. In the entry you give above it is `online`. You can clear the `howpublished` field without having to edit the `bib` file. Details can be found in [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/4483).

Comment: I found also in the manual that 'type' does not work. Thanks for the link. That exactly does what I need.

Comment: Good to hear. Using the `type` or `nottype` options wouldn't fix your problem - they simply filter entries by type. For example `type=online` makes `\printbibliography` list only `online` entries.

Answer (score 2):

*(answer / long comment with pic)*

From your description I gathered the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{guizzo_i-limb_2008,
title = {{i-LIMB} snatches {MacRobert} Award - {IEEE} Spectrum},
url = {http://spectrum.ieee.org/automaton/robotics/robotics-software/ilimb_snatches_macrobert_award},
abstract = {{IEEE} Spectrum},
journal = {{IEEE} Spectrum},
author = {Guizzo, Erico},
month = jun,
year = {2008}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

No matter whether I use `backend=biber` or `backend=biblatex`, I can't reproduce your problem, this is my output:

[image]

Make sure your system is up-to-date. If that doesn't help, please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces your problem.

Comment: My system is as up to date as possible (miktex2.9 updated yesterday) ;-) I tried to build a MWE and the funny thing is: The problem dissapears =-/. I will now try to strip down my 1600 lines bib file down to find the problem (puuuuuh) @doncherry

Comment: BTW: I am using book not article

Comment: You could as well try getting rid of all auxiliary files (e.g. via `latexmk -c foo.tex`) and comiling again. If that doesn't help, let us know when you've got the MWE. The difference between `article` and `book` doesn't matter in this case, hence using `article` is better for a MWE since it's simpler.

Comment: I have a MWE on the latex side. Not yet on the bib file side. If I isolate the entry I do not have that behaviour anymore =-(

Comment: Try eliminating small bits of your source and compile to see where the error disappears.