# Suppress a biblatex field in only one of split bibliographies?

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I am aware of `\clearfield`, `\clearlist` etc (cf. [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex)) - but I'm really not sure how to apply it in this context:

Say you have a split bibliography (i.e. several calls to `\printbibliography` in one document). How can you filter a specific field in a bibliography item - but only in one bibliography (i.e. only in one call to `\printbibliography`)?

For instance, in the MWE below (compiles with `pdflatex test.tex && biber test && pdflatex test.tex && pdflatex test.tex`), let's say I'd like to filter `urldate` (i.e. `urldate` is not typeset) *only* in the first bibliography - but for the second one, the original/default behavior should be restored (i.e. `urldate` is typeset). How to I do that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ctan,
  title        = {CTAN},
  date         = 2006,
  url          = {http://www.ctan.org},
  subtitle     = {The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network},
  urldate      = {2006-10-01},
  label        = {CTAN},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
}
@misc{google,
  title        = {Google},
  date         = 2007,
  url          = {http://www.google.com},
  urldate      = {2007-10-01},
}
@misc{hotmail,
  title        = {Hotmail},
  date         = 2008,
  url          = {http://www.hotmail.com},
  urldate      = {2008-10-01},
}
@misc{yahoo,
  title        = {Yahoo},
  date         = 2009,
  url          = {http://www.yahoo.com},
  urldate      = {2009-10-01},
}
@misc{aol,
  title        = {AOL},
  date         = 2010,
  url          = {http://www.aol.com},
  urldate      = {2010-10-01},
}
@misc{altavista,
  title        = {AltaVista},
  date         = 2011,
  url          = {http://www.altavista.com},
  urldate      = {2011-10-01},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\begin{refsection}

Citing some stuff here: first \cite{ctan}, then \cite{google}, and finally \cite{hotmail}.

\printbibliography[sorting=none,section=\therefsection,resetnumbers=true]

\end{refsection}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{refsection}

Citing some stuff here: first \cite{yahoo}, then \cite{aol}, and finally \cite{altavista}.

\printbibliography[sorting=none,section=\therefsection,resetnumbers=true]

\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: test.png]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbool{clearurl}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
 \ifbool{clearurl}
  {%
   \clearfield{urlday}%
   \clearfield{urlmonth}%
   \clearfield{urlyear}%
  }{}%
  }

\begin{document}

Citing some stuff here: first \cite{ctan}

\booltrue{clearurl}
\printbibliography


\boolfalse{clearurl}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: test.png]

Comment: Many thanks for that, @UlrikeFischer - looks great; I also added an image to your example - cheers!

Answer (score 3):

We can define a new command for that: `\AtEveryBibitemNextBibOnly` (what a name), it combines the best of `\AtEveryBibitem` and `\AtNextBibliography`.

```
\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\AtEveryBibitemNextBibOnly}{%
  \ifundef\blx@hook@bibitem@save
    {\global\let\blx@hook@bibitem@save\blx@hook@bibitem
     \preto\blx@endbibliography{\global\let\blx@hook@bibitem\blx@hook@bibitem@save
                                \global\undef\blx@hook@bibitem@save}}
    {}%
  \gappto\blx@hook@bibitem}
\makeatother
```

Essentially, it saves the current definition of what `\AtEveryBibitem` does and appends all the code you feed it to the `\AtEveryBibitem`, but the old definition of `\AtEveryBibitem` is restored after the next bibliography.

So all code you add via `\AtEveryBibitemNextBibOnly` is executed for every item in the next bibliography (and only in the next bibliography).

In our example we then only need

```
\AtEveryBibitemNextBibOnly{\clearfield{urlyear}}
```

right before the bibliography where we want to suppress the `urldate`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true,style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\AtEveryBibitemNextBibOnly}{%
  \ifundef\blx@hook@bibitem@save
    {\global\let\blx@hook@bibitem@save\blx@hook@bibitem
     \preto\blx@endbibliography{\global\let\blx@hook@bibitem\blx@hook@bibitem@save
                                \global\undef\blx@hook@bibitem@save}}
    {}%
  \gappto\blx@hook@bibitem}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{refsection}
Citing some stuff here: first \cite{ctan}, then \cite{markey}.
\AtEveryBibitemNextBibOnly{\clearfield{urlyear}}
\printbibliography[sorting=none,section=\therefsection,resetnumbers=true]
\end{refsection}

\section{Section 2}
\begin{refsection}
Citing some stuff here: first \cite{ctan}, then \cite{markey}.
\printbibliography[sorting=none,section=\therefsection,resetnumbers=true]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that @moewe - great to have this approach in mind, though I liked UlrikeFischer's approach a bit better; cheers!