# Iterate over all the entries in a bib file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, luatex

I have a big `bib` file that contains a lot of entries such that most of them contain a `note` filed. I would like to automatically iterate over all the entries and for each entry insert into the document something like:

```
Paper's title / First author (et al. if needed) [x]
Note:
The content of the note field.
```

where `[x]` is the entry's number in the list of references that is printed.

If I know the entry's key, then using `biblatex` this could be something like:

```
\newcommand{\completecite}[1]{
  \citetitle{#1}, \citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}

  \citefield{#1}{note}
}
```

My problem is how to iterate over all the entries in the `bib` file?

Probably this can be solved using a combination of `lua` and `biblatex`. But my question is whether there's a simple and canonical way to do it? And otherwise, I would be happy to get a hint how to tackle this using `lua`.

In short, the ultimate goal is to keep track of all the papers and manually added notes in a single `bib` file and generate a pdf that contains the notes for each entry.

Comment: You could write your own bib driver in `biblatex` and use `\nocite`, but for what you want the relatively recent package [`citeall`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeall) seems very relevant.

Comment: If I understand correctly `biblatex`'s driver kicks in only when there is a `cite` command. Isn't it so? I cannot opne the documentation of `citeall` package.

Comment: If you use `\nocite{*}` all available `.bib` entries are "cited" in that they appear in the bibliography. I can open the [documentation of the `citeall` pacakge](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/citeall/citeall.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can effectively use a `\printbibliography` if we do some black magic.

First we define an universal driver

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citetitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{drorver}{%
  \usebibmacro{citetitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \par
  \printfield{note}%
}
```

and a new list format

```
\defbibenvironment{drorlist}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
```

And then the magic

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makealldror}{\def\blx@driver##1{\csuse{blx@bbx@drorver}}}
\makeatother
```

this makes all entries use the `drorver` type.
The macro `blx@driver` is used to call the relevant driver for the correct entry type (`\blx@bbx@<type>`) we make that macro choose `\blx@bbx@drorver` at all times. (See `biblatex2.sty`, line 1665 for the real definition of `\blx@driver`)

And then we use

```
\begingroup
\makealldror
\printbibliography[env=drorlist]
\endgroup
```

to typeset a list of the form you want.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{citeall}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{batty2007iq,
title={IQ in early adulthood and later cancer risk: cohort study of one million Swedish men},
author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
journal={Annals of Oncology},
volume={18},
number={1},
pages={21--28},
year={2007},
publisher={European Society for Medical Oncology},
note = {ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum},
}

@article{batty2007premorbid,
title={Premorbid (early life) IQ and Later Mortality Risk: Systematic Review},
author={Batty, G. David and Deary, Ian J. and Gottfredson, Linda S.},
journal={Annals of Epidemiology},
volume={17},
number={4},
pages={278--288},
year={2007},
publisher={Elsevier},
note = {Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem},
}

@article{batty2009iq_early,
title={IQ in Early Adulthood and Mortality By Middle Age: Cohort Study of 1 Million Swedish Men},
author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
journal={Epidemiology},
volume={20},
number={1},
pages={100--109},
year={2009},
publisher={LWW},
note = {In Mexico is een man gearresteerd.},
}

@article{batty2009iq_socio,
title={IQ in Early Adulthood, Socioeconomic Position, and Unintentional Injury Mortality by Middle Age: A Cohort Study of More Than 1 Million Swedish Men},
author={Batty, G. David and Gale, Catharine R. and Tynelius, Per and Deary, Ian J. and Rasmussen, Finn},
journal={American Journal of Epidemiology},
volume={169},
number={5},
pages={606--615},
year={2009},
publisher={Oxford University Press},
note = {Lore ipsum dolor sit amet \begin{itemize}\item Lorem\end{itemize}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citetitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


\DeclareBibliographyDriver{drorver}{%
  \usebibmacro{citetitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \par
  \printfield{note}%
}

\defbibenvironment{drorlist}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makealldror}{\def\blx@driver##1{\csuse{blx@bbx@drorver}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\begingroup
\makealldror
\printbibliography[env=drorlist]
\endgroup

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

We can use the [`citeall`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeall) package for this task.

First we need to define a nice cite macro for the job. It is mostly cobbled together from the standard `.cbx` files.

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citetitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{drorcite}{%
  \usebibmacro{citetitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \par
  \printfield{note}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\drorcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{drorcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

and then just

```
\citeall[\drorcite]
```

and all entries in the `.bib` file are cited with `\drorcite`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{citeall}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{batty2007iq,
title={IQ in early adulthood and later cancer risk: cohort study of one million Swedish men},
author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
journal={Annals of Oncology},
volume={18},
number={1},
pages={21--28},
year={2007},
publisher={European Society for Medical Oncology},
note = {ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum},
}

@article{batty2007premorbid,
title={Premorbid (early life) IQ and Later Mortality Risk: Systematic Review},
author={Batty, G. David and Deary, Ian J. and Gottfredson, Linda S.},
journal={Annals of Epidemiology},
volume={17},
number={4},
pages={278--288},
year={2007},
publisher={Elsevier},
note = {Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem},
}

@article{batty2009iq_early,
title={IQ in Early Adulthood and Mortality By Middle Age: Cohort Study of 1 Million Swedish Men},
author={Batty, G. David and Wennerstad, Karin Modig and Smith, George Davey and Gunnell, David and Deary, Ian J. and Tynelius, Per and Rasmussen, Finn},
journal={Epidemiology},
volume={20},
number={1},
pages={100--109},
year={2009},
publisher={LWW},
note = {In Mexico is een man gearresteerd.},
}

@article{batty2009iq_socio,
title={IQ in Early Adulthood, Socioeconomic Position, and Unintentional Injury Mortality by Middle Age: A Cohort Study of More Than 1 Million Swedish Men},
author={Batty, G. David and Gale, Catharine R. and Tynelius, Per and Deary, Ian J. and Rasmussen, Finn},
journal={American Journal of Epidemiology},
volume={169},
number={5},
pages={606--615},
year={2009},
publisher={Oxford University Press},
note = {Lore ipsum dolor sit amet},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\newbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:shorthand}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{citetitle}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:title}}%
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\newbibmacro*{drorcite}{%
  \usebibmacro{citetitle}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{year}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printtext[brackets]{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
  \par
  \printfield{note}%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\drorcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{drorcite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\begin{document}
\citeall[\drorcite]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What would be the limitations of the formatting that can be used inside the `note` fields? Seems like `itemize` break this approach...

Comment: @Dror That is probably a limitation imposed by how `citeall` works. If you can live with a document where you can't have a normal bibliography, I could cook something up.

Comment: It seems like all I need is to iterate over the keys and pass them to the command I have in the OP. I actually consider using python for that, but would prefer a self-contained TeXy solution.

Comment: @Dror Try the edit, please.

Comment: Magic indeed! Two more requests: 1) Can you add some comments to the magic so I could maintain it and reuse it? 2) How can I avoid the rendering of "References" twice?

Comment: Ohh... and 3) how can I remove the `note` from the second instance? Namely, have the content of `note` appear only in the "intext citation" part?

Comment: @Dror For 1 I have added a short comment. And for 2 you might just need `heading=none`.

Comment: No 3 can be solved like in [Suppress a biblatex field in only one of split bibliographies?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245408/35864)

Comment: @Dror: The error with itemize is due to the fact that biblatex has a `\list` command too, citeall redefines it when reading the entries but doesn't reset it before it prints the entries. I will update the package in a few days (I will have to do some more tests).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `citeall`. But if you have entries without note field, you will probably have to define a better `\completecite` command. Also be aware that `citeall` was written to test and debug new cite styles and not for "document loops".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{citeall}
\newcommand{\completecite}[1]{%
  \citetitle{#1}, \citeauthor{#1} \cite{#1}
  \par
  \citefield{#1}{note}\par
}
\begin{document}
\citeall[\completecite]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Of course. But my toenails curl up when I see definitions such as `\completecite` here.

Comment: @moewe: For a fast test I would something like `\completecite` too.

Comment: For fast tests that would be fine. But if you want to have a proper citation command, `\DeclareCiteCommand` is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: This seems to be a good start. However, having `itemize` in the `note` field breaks this approach, while using the command in my OP handles the list properly. Any workaround?