# Cite all references in the text

Tags: biblatex

I would like to cite all works in the text with a single command (e.g., `\cite{*}`), best in alphabetical order.

To clarify: I don't want the references to appear only in the bibliography (as it could be achieved with the `\nocite{*}` command) and I don't want to paste all bibkeys in the command.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: `in the following references$^{1--37}$, ...`?? ;^)

Comment: Related [Iterate over all the entries in a bib file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268178/35864)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `biblatex` you use Ulrike Fischer's [`citeall`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeall) package.

Simply type `\citeall` to cite all sources. If you want to use a different command than `\cite`, use `\citeall[<command>]`, e.g. `\citeall[\fullcite]` to `\fullcite` all sources from the `.bib` file.

Since the format of the `.bbl` file changed a bit since the last release of `citeall`, I needed a bit of extra code to get it to run properly.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{citeall}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  date         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}

@book{maron,
  author       = {Maron, Monika},
  title        = {Animal Triste},
  date         = 2000,
  translator   = {Brigitte Goldstein},
  origlanguage = {german},
  publisher    = {University of Nebraska Press},
  location     = {Lincoln},
}

@book{worman,
  author       = {Worman, Nancy},
  title        = {The Cast of Character},
  date         = 2002,
  publisher    = {University of Texas Press},
  location     = {Austin},
}

@thesis{geer,
  author       = {de Geer, Ingrid},
  title        = {Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald~-- and Music},
  type         = {phdthesis},
  institution  = {Uppsala Universitet},
  date         = 1985,
  subtitle     = {The {Orkney Earldom} of the Twelfth Century. {A} Musicological
                  Study},
  location     = {Uppsala},
  options      = {useprefix=false},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Nn \_UFca_init_bblfields:
 {\newcommand\true [2][]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\field[3][]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\name [5][]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\strng[2]{\ignorespaces}%
  \renewenvironment{refsection}[1]{}{\ignorespaces}
  \newenvironment{sortlist}[2][]{}{\ignorespaces}
  %\renewcommand\verb{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\@gobble}{\my@verb}}
  \def\verb##1\endverb{\ignorespaces}
  \renewcommand\list[4][]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\inset[1]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\keyw[1]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\set[1]{\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\warn[1]{\ignorespaces}
  \renewcommand\inset[1]{\addtocategory{citeall}{##1}\ignorespaces}
  \newcommand\range[2]{\ignorespaces} %for biblatex-dev
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\citeall
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```