# How to partially enable a field in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

To produce an annotated reading list, I want to present the reader with two components of the list:
a) a thematically sorted, annotated part
b) an alphabetically sorted, non-annotated part

I use biblatex-chicago.
I do note the points of an earlier [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex) on suppressing fields. My question is how I can keep a field enabled for (a) whilst disabing it for (b)?

One option I recognise is, of course, to not work on this via fields, but annotate in the main tex file, outside of the bib-file. Ideally, I would want to use a solution that can work with fields in the bib file.

Comment: Please check [Suppress a biblatex field in only one of split bibliographies?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245408/35864). If you need further assistance you can make it easier for people to help you by providing a short example document (an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)) so we can test our solutions and ensure they work for your set up.

Comment: thanks!  "Suppress a biblatex field in only one of split bibliographies?" provided the answer I needed.

Comment: Fine, I have voted to close your question as a duplicate of the linked one then.