biblatex: multiple reference lists, suppressing a field only in one of them
Edit: As @moeve kindly points out in the comments below, this question of mine is almost a duplicate to
Suppress a biblatex field in only one of split bibliographies?
The only difference is that I use the "category" feature of biblatex to split my bibliographies.  As a result, the solution is somewhat easier for my case.
[I'm not sure what to do with this thread. Tentatively I'll write a solution below using the "category" feature. But, perhaps I should mark this as duplicate and add the solution to the other thread. . . ]

I print multiple reference lists in a single document and I'd like to suppress the article title only in one of the reference lists. I've tried to use \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{title}} but found that this declaration is global (allowed only in the preamble).
Formally, my question is a subset of using multiple citation styles as in
Biblatex multiple citation styles in the same document .  If this is the only answer, I'd try to adopt the method described there.
I know you could edit the bib database file to achieve the goal but I'd like to avoid that.
What method is available? I attach a simple LaTeX code below. (In my real document, I use the "category" mechanism of biblatex to print different lists in different sections but in the example I omitted the categories. I hope this omission won't affect the solution.)
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{entry1,
  author =   {Author, A. and Buthor, B. and Cusor, C.},
  title =    {Title A},
  journal =      {Journal A},
  volume =       {50},
  year =       {2050},
  pages =    {63--90},
}
@article{entry2,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {Title of Article B},
  journal =      {Journal B},
  volume =       {50},
  year =       {2013},
  pages =    {63--90},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{one}
\cite{entry1,entry2}
\printbibliography
\section{two}
\cite{entry1,entry2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}


Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/245408/35864 help?

If this is controlled by bibliography categories, you can do even better than Ulrike's answer in this case. Just say \ifcategory{<category name>} instead of \ifbool{clearurl}. (You may have to reverse the true and false branches depending on the desired outcome. You won't need the \newbool{clearurl} or the \booltrue{clearurl}/\boolfalse{clearurl}.)

@moewe I see! So, the basic idea is to use an "if" branching within \AtEveryBibitem.  I'll try the idea for my real code and write an answer here if I'm successful.

As @moewe pointed out in the comments, the problem is solved by modifying a solution from
Suppress a biblatex field in only one of split bibliographies?
That is, put the following
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifcategory{<category name>}{\clearfield{title}}{}%
}

in the preamble. This solution is easier than that shown in the quoted thread because I use the "category" feature to split my bibliographies.
