# How to suppress specific bibtex entry (e.g., language) without biblatex package

Tags: bibtex, amsplain

In [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex?noredirect=1&lq=1) a related question was asked. The following can suppress language field from appearing in the output, when **biblatex** package is present.

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{language}} % clears language
```

How to achieve this suppression without biblatex package (i.e., in plain bibtex)?
I am using `amsplain` as bibtex style.
The bibtex file is something like this (provided by https://zbmath.org/):

```
@Article{zbMATH02658504,
    Author = {A. {Einstein}},
    Title = {{Eine Theorie der Grundlagen der Thermodynamik.}},
    FJournal = {{Annalen der Physik, IV. Folge}},
    Journal = {{Ann. der Phys. (4)}},
    ISSN = {0003-3804},
    Volume = {11},
    Pages = {170--187},
    Year = {1903},
    Publisher = {Johann Ambrosius Barth, Leipzig},
    Language = {German},
    Zbl = {34.0962.01}
}
```

Comment: in general you'd just modify the bst style to not use the language field, but the details depend on the bst that you are modifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amsplain.bst` has

```
% The extra section to write out a language field was added
% for AMSPLAIN.BST.  Not present in plain.bst.

FUNCTION {format.language}
{ language empty$
    { "" }
    { " (" language * ")" * }
  if$
}
```

This tests if the language field is empty and does nothing or outputs it in `()` depending.

So if you make a copy of that file called say `xamsplain.bst` and use

```
\bibliographystyle{xamsplain}
```

and  then modify the definition always to do nothing

```
FUNCTION {format.language}
    { "" }
```