# How do I suppress author and location in a patent bibliography?

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to suppress the rendering of location and authors in a bibliography of patents, but an unable to find documentation on how to accomplish this.

The example below, is my attempt, based on the logic of [related questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32930/7844) here, but is having no effect.

How do I suppress author and location in a patent bibliography?

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[]{biblatex-chicago}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{patent}{
    \clearfield{author}%
    \clearfield{location}%
}{}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test-lit.bib}
@patent{lens.org/072-791-597-282-659,
    number = {US 8574659 B2},
    type = {Granted Patent},
    title = {Healthcare Information Management Evidence},
    author = {Author A, Author B},
    date = {2019-09-03},
    location = {United States},
    url = {https://lens.org/072-111-222-333-444}
}

@patent{lens.org/179-367-355-357-993,
    number = {US 0195811 B2},
    type = {Granted Patent},
    title = {Food Supply  Automation Grocery Method},
    author = {Author A, Author B, Author C},
    date = {2019-08-27},
    location = {United States},
    url = {https://lens.org/777-111-888-333-000}
}

@patent{lens.org/117-614-886-875-323,
    number = {US 114252345 B2},
    type = {Granted Patent},
    title = {Methods And Systems For Methods And Systems},
    author = {Author A, Author B, Author C},
    date = {2019-08-27},
    location = {United States},
    url = {https://lens.org/444-111-555-333-666}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test-lit.bib}

\nocite{*}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\printbibliography
```

Comment: `author` is a name list, so you need `\clearname{author}` and `location` is a list, so you need `\clearlist{location}`. (You are also missing a `%` after `\ifentrytype{patent}{` and another one after the `}{}` in `\AtEveryBibitem`.)

Comment: Cool. That's an answer!