# How to suppress annotation field from .bbl file in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I would like to suppress the annotation field from the .bbl file using biblatex.  I often use the annotation field to write down notes about a given paper, which can be a problem if I happen to use a LaTeX command such as % in the annotation field.  Having something like % in the annotation field does not cause any issues in the .bib file, but having it in the .bbl file causes a failure to compile.  I tried to follow the suggestions in [Is it possible to suppress a specific field from bibtex .bbl in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex), but these did not work for me.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.bib}
@article{Doe.J-1979a,
    Annote = {10 % strain},
    Author = {John Doe},
    Date-Added = {2020-08-27 10:54:17 -0600},
    Date-Modified = {2020-08-27 12:03:22 -0600},
    Journal = {Journal of LaTeX Issues},
    Title = {Problematic Reference Title},
    Year = {1979}}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{annotation}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=annotation, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\textcite{Doe.J-1979a}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This creates the following .bbl file

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{ver@biblatex.sty}
  {\@latex@error
     {Missing 'biblatex' package}
     {The bibliography requires the 'biblatex' package.}
      \aftergroup\endinput}
  {}
\endgroup


\refsection{0}
  \datalist[entry]{nty/global//global/global}
    \entry{Doe.J-1979a}{article}{}
      \name{author}{1}{}{%
        {{hash=bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}{%
           family={Doe},
           familyi={D\bibinitperiod},
           given={John},
           giveni={J\bibinitperiod}}}%
      }
      \strng{namehash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \strng{fullhash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \strng{bibnamehash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \strng{authorbibnamehash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \strng{authornamehash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \strng{authorfullhash}{bd051a2f7a5f377e3a62581b0e0f8577}
      \field{sortinit}{D}
      \field{sortinithash}{2ef1bd9a78cc71eb74d7231c635177b8}
      \field{labelnamesource}{author}
      \field{labeltitlesource}{title}
      \field{annotation}{10 % strain}
      \field{journaltitle}{Journal of LaTeX Issues}
      \field{title}{Problematic Reference Title}
      \field{year}{1979}
    \endentry
  \enddatalist
\endrefsection
\endinput
```

As you can see, the `%` messes up the closing bracket in `\field{annotation}{10 % strain}`.

Comment: in your example you called your field `Annote` not annotation.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, thanks for your attention to detail, but I believe I did things correctly.  The `Annote` field in the .bib file gets converted to an `annotation` field in the .bbl file.  I have updated my original post to show this.

Comment: If you replace `annotation` with `annote` in the definition of the step of the `\DeclareSourcemap` instruction, the annotation is ignored (nullified) and it will not appear in the `bbl` file.

Comment: Hah, that was it!  @Guido, if you would submit your suggestion as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MWE, the `.bib` file contains the field `annote`, but in the source map, the step specify `annotation` as a field. Hence,  if in the source map we replace `annotation` with `annote` the field containing `%` will be nullified and it will not appear in the `bbl` file.  Accordingly, the `\DeclareSourcemap` instruction should look like:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=annote, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Guido](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16895/guido) has already given the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560378/35864): You need to delete the `annote` field in your sourcemap. But it may be interesting to know why.

`biblatex` has some field and type aliases set up for backwards compatibility with some popular BibTeX styles. One such alias relation turns the `annote` field into `annotation`. With Biber this alias relation is implemented via a special *driver sourcemap* defined in `biblatex.def` ([ll. 1305-1337 in v3.15a](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/e5d6e69e61613cc33ab1fcc2083a8277eb9cfce5/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L1305-L1337))

```
\DeclareDriverSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  <...>
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=hyphenation,   fieldtarget=langid]
    \step[fieldsource=address,       fieldtarget=location]
    \step[fieldsource=school,        fieldtarget=institution]
    \step[fieldsource=annote,        fieldtarget=annotation]
    \step[fieldsource=archiveprefix, fieldtarget=eprinttype]
    \step[fieldsource=journal,       fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    \step[fieldsource=primaryclass,  fieldtarget=eprintclass]
    \step[fieldsource=key,           fieldtarget=sortkey]
    \step[fieldsource=pdf,           fieldtarget=file]
  }
}
```

This just says to turn every `annote` Biber finds into `annotation`. Indeed you could say that internally for `biblatex` there is only `annotation` and no `annote` field. So it is natural to write all code mentioning only `annotation` and not `annote`.

The problem you ran into was timing: This driver sourcemap is executed *after* your user-level simple `\DeclareSourcemap`. In particular, when your sourcemap is executed, no field names have been renamed yet and the field is still called `annote`.

One way to resolve the problem is shown in Guido's answer: Delete the `annote` field, since that's what it is still called when your sourcemap is executed. You may or may not want to delete `annotation` as well

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=annote,     null]
      \step[fieldset=annotation, null]
    }
  }
}
```

One other way to get around the issue be to execute the `annote`->`annotation` mapping already in your sourcemap: So you first map all `annote`s to `annotation` and then delete the `annotation`.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=annote,  fieldtarget=annotation]
      \step[fieldset=annotation, null]
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note that in any case `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{annotation}}` won't help because the error you get from the `%` already occurs when the entry data is read from the `.bbl` file and not when the field is/could be printed in the bibliography. What's more the standard `biblatex` styles (except for `reading`) don't show `annotation` anyway, so the `\clearfield` wouldn't do anything useful in the MWE.

Answer (score 0):

Add `annotation=false` to the settings, e.g.: `\usepackage[style=apa,annotation=false]{biblatex}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!